# Sprite Kit customFieldWithEvaluationBlock - block not called

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I created a new SpriteKit iOS project and added this code to GameScene.m.  The block to calculate the force field is never called, so node `n1` never moves. Anyone know why? What am I missing?

```
@implementation GameScene

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    // Create a red circle in the middle of scene
    SKShapeNode *n1 = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:20];
    n1.fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
    n1.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 2);
    n1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:20];
    n1.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
    n1.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    [self addChild:n1];

    // Try to add a custom force field to the scene
    SKFieldNode *f1 = [SKFieldNode customFieldWithEvaluationBlock:^vector_float3(vector_float3 position, vector_float3 velocity, float mass, float charge, NSTimeInterval deltaTime) {
        printf("block called\n");
        vector_float3 res = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
        return res;
    }];
    f1.enabled = YES;
    [self addChild:f1];
}
```

Comment: Have you set the position for the SKFieldNode?

Comment: If I don't, it defaults to (0,0). If I do set it, to say (10,10), that makes no difference.